# How do I run a ListenableWorker work on a background thread?

Tags: android, performance, background, android-architecture-components, android-workmanager

Since I need to perform work asynchronously in WorkManager, I need to use the `ListenableWorker`, which by default runs on the main (UI) thread. Since this work could be a long processing tasks that could freeze the interface, I wanted to perform it on a background thread. In the [Working with WorkManager (Android Dev Summit '18) video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=83a4rYXsDs0&t=1480s), the Google engineer showed how to manually configure WorkManager to run works on a custom `Executor`, so I followed his guidance:

1) Disable the default WorkManager initializer in the AndroidManifest:

```
<provider
    android:name="androidx.work.impl.WorkManagerInitializer"
    android:authorities="com.example.myapp.workmanager-init"
    tools:node="remove" />
```

2) In Application.onCreate, initialize WorkManager with the custom configuration, which in my case is this:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration.Builder().setExecutor(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()).build();
        WorkManager.initialize(this, configuration);
    }
}
```

Now my actual `ListenableWorker` is this:

```
@NonNull
    @Override
    public ListenableFuture<Result> startWork() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Work started.");
        mFuture = ResolvableFuture.create();
        Result result = doWork();
        mFuture.set(result);
        return mFuture;
    }

    private Result doWork() {
        Log.d(TAG, "isMainThread? " + isMainThread());
        mFusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                if (location != null) {
                    // Since I still don't know how to communicate with the UI, I will just log the location
                    Log.d(TAG, "Last location: " + location);
                    return Result.success();
                } else {
                    return Result.failure();
                }
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return Result.failure();
            }
        });
    }

    private boolean isMainThread() {
        return Looper.getMainLooper().getThread() == Thread.currentThread();
    }
```

Why does the `isMainThread()` method return true even though I specified the `Executor` WorkManager should use as a new background thread and how can I actually run that piece of work on a background thread?

**EDIT:** `ListenableWorker` with the need of a `CountDownLatch`.
Since I need to reschedule the work everytime it succeeds (workaround for the 15 minutes minimum interval for `PeriodicWorkRequest`), I need to do it after the previous piece of work returns success, otherwise I have weird behavior. This is needed because, apparently, `ExistingWorkPolicy.APPEND` doesn't work as expected.
Use case is to request location updates with high accuracy at a pretty frequent interval (5-10s), even in background. Turned on and off by an SMS, even when the app is not running (but not force-stopped), or through a button (It's an university project).

```
public class LocationWorker extends ListenableWorker {

    static final String UNIQUE_WORK_NAME = "LocationWorker";
    static final String KEY_NEW_LOCATION = "new_location";
    private static final String TAG = "LocationWorker";
    private ResolvableFuture<Result> mFuture;
    private LocationCallback mLocationCallback;
    private CountDownLatch mLatch;
    private Context mContext;

    public LocationWorker(@NonNull final Context appContext, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
        super(appContext, workerParams);
        mContext = appContext;
        Utils.setRequestingLocationUpdates(mContext, true);
        mLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                LocationUtils.getInstance(mContext).removeLocationUpdates(this);
                Location location = locationResult.getLastLocation();
                Log.d(TAG, "Work " + getId() + " returned: " + location);
                mFuture.set(Result.success(Utils.getOutputData(location)));
                // Rescheduling work
                OneTimeWorkRequest request = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(LocationWorker.class).setInitialDelay(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();
                WorkManager.getInstance().enqueueUniqueWork(LocationWorker.UNIQUE_WORK_NAME, ExistingWorkPolicy.KEEP, request);
                Log.d(TAG, "Rescheduling work. New ID: " + request.getId());
                // Relase lock
                mLatch.countDown();
            }
        };
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ListenableFuture<Result> startWork() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Starting work " + getId());
        mFuture = ResolvableFuture.create();
        LocationUtils.getInstance(mContext).requestSingleUpdate(mLocationCallback, new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                LocationUtils.getInstance(mContext).removeLocationUpdates(mLocationCallback);
                Utils.setRequestingLocationUpdates(mContext, false);
                WorkManager.getInstance().cancelUniqueWork(UNIQUE_WORK_NAME);
                mFuture.set(Result.failure());
                // Relase lock
                mLatch.countDown();
            }
        });
        try {
            mLatch.await(5L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mFuture;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want to continuously (i.e., less than every 60 seconds), you **absolutely** should be using a [foreground service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services#Foreground) and **not** WorkManager, which is for, as per [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/):

> **deferrable,** asynchronous tasks

And not something that needs to run near continously.

However, if you do proceed to incorrectly use WorkManager, you'd want to keep the following in mind:

Your custom `doWork` method runs on the main thread because as per the [setExecutor() documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/Configuration.Builder.html#setExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor)):

> An Executor for running [Worker](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/Worker.html)s

Specifically, only the [Worker](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/Worker) subclass of `ListenableWorker` runs on a background thread provided by the `Executor` - **not** your `ListenableWorker` implementation.

As per the [ListenableWorker.startWork() documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/ListenableWorker.html#startWork()):

> This method is called on the main thread.

Because you're using `ListenableWorker`, your `startWork` method is being called on the main thread, as expected. Since you call your own `doWork()` method on the same thread, you'll still be on the main thread.

In your case, you don't need to care about what thread you're on and you don't need any `Executor` since it doesn't matter what thread you call `getLastLocation()` on.

Instead, you need to only call `set` on your `ResolvableFuture` when you actually have a result - i.e., in the `onSuccess()` or `onFailure` callbacks. This is the signal to `WorkManager` that you're actually done with your work:

```
public class LocationWorker extends ListenableWorker {

    static final String UNIQUE_WORK_NAME = "LocationWorker";
    static final String KEY_NEW_LOCATION = "new_location";
    private static final String TAG = "LocationWorker";
    private ResolvableFuture<Result> mFuture;
    private LocationCallback mLocationCallback;

    public LocationWorker(@NonNull final Context appContext, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
        super(appContext, workerParams);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ListenableFuture<Result> startWork() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Starting work " + getId());
        mFuture = ResolvableFuture.create();
        Utils.setRequestingLocationUpdates(getApplicationContext(), true);
        mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                LocationUtils.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).removeLocationUpdates(this);
                Location location = locationResult.getLastLocation();
                Log.d(TAG, "Work " + getId() + " returned: " + location);
                // Rescheduling work
                OneTimeWorkRequest request = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(LocationWorker.class).setInitialDelay(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();
                WorkManager.getInstance().enqueueUniqueWork(LocationWorker.UNIQUE_WORK_NAME, ExistingWorkPolicy.KEEP, request);
                Log.d(TAG, "Rescheduling work. New ID: " + request.getId());

                // Always set the result as the last operation
                mFuture.set(Result.success(Utils.getOutputData(location)));
            }
        };
        LocationUtils.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).requestSingleUpdate(mLocationCallback, new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                LocationUtils.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).removeLocationUpdates(mLocationCallback);
                Utils.setRequestingLocationUpdates(getApplicationContext(), false);
                WorkManager.getInstance().cancelUniqueWork(UNIQUE_WORK_NAME);
                mFuture.set(Result.failure());
            }
        });
        return mFuture;
    }
}
```

Comment: So since `Worker` is a subclass of `ListenableWorker`, setExecutor() only sets the custom `Executor` `Worker`s and **not** `ListenableWorker`s, like in my case? Having said that, it's impossible to perform work in `ListenableWorker` on a background thread? As per WorkManager's code, `Worker` is able to perform work on background by using getBackgroundExecutor() and I would like to do the same in my `ListenableWorker`... is it possible? I used setExecutor() because another Google engineer suggested here: 
 https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/122066789  Thanks.

Comment: You don't need any `Executor` for what you're doing - the `FusedLocationProviderClient` is taking care of that for you.

Comment: `FusedLocationProviderClient` automatically runs on a separate thread regardless of how you called it?  
If, like I do, I have another `ListenableWorker` for a Retrofit request, I think I would need to manually define the background executor, wouldn't I?

Comment: If you're already using an API that has a callback, they're either already doing the threading for you (since they obviously can't block your thread) or they offer an optional API that takes an Executor as an overload.

Comment: Ok now I understood better what you meant: the actual computation happens on the thread specified by that API, only the callback is executed on my thread, correct?  
I've got one last question: as I previously said, the `Worker` class, which is the synchronous implementation of `WorkManager`, execute whatever code you put in doWork() on a background thread (proven by the isMainThread() method in the question and **). Well, how can I run whatever code I put in `ListenableWorker`'s `startWork()`? This is the actual question since the beginning, still unanswered. Thank you for understanding.

Comment: ** by looking at the [source code](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_support/blob/androidx-master-dev/work/workmanager/src/main/java/androidx/work/Worker.java#L81)

Comment: I've updated my answer to point out the documentation on `startWork()` that is explicitly always the main thread. In your case, because you're using an API that has a callback style API, it doesn't matter at all what thread you're on.

Comment: Now I am in the need of using a `CountDownLatch` so I definitely need to run the `ListenableWorker` code in another thread to avoid busy waiting on the UI thread, so maybe I could get an answer to the original question 

Comment: No, you don't. Please update your question with your fixed `ListenableWorker` (only calling `set` when you actually have a result) and where you are attempting to use a `CountDownLatch`.

Comment: I've updated my answer with an explanation that WorkManager is absolutely not the API you want to be using for your particular problem. I also added code that explains exactly what I mean by calling `set()` only when you have a result. I think the point you were missing is that you don't need to wait for `set()` to be called to return the `ResolvableFuture` - you return the `ResolvableFuture` immediately, and WorkManager will wait for you to call `set()` at some later time.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I already did a version of the app which used a foreground service, but I don't know why, it felt ugly to me. So I looked at the new Google `WorkManager` API and it looked interesting. But since a Google engineer explicitly told me the best solution to fetch the user location is to use a foreground service, I will trust him and use it. I'll just use `WorkManager` when uploading the user location to my server because I think the use case here fits well `WorkManager`. Thanks again!

Comment: Two questions on the foreground `Service`, if I may ask: 1) The service should be promoted to foreground only if the `Activity` is in background, and vice versa (`startForeground()` shows the notification even if started when the `Activity` is in foreground): considering it's all inside my process, should I implement this logic extending the `Binder` class? 2) What is the best practice on updating the UI when the `Service` gets a new `location`? I'm thinking of a `LocalBroadcastManager` but was wondering what was the advice of a Google engineer. Thanks for clearing my doubts and improving me!

Comment: Thank you @ianhanniballake for a very useful example of how to use `ListenableWorker` rather than `Worker`... would be great if the official docs could include such an example rather than focussing on `Worker` and just stating that you should use `ListenableWorker` when async work needs to be done.  Appreciate that this API is still in beta, but it's a really really useful API that seems to tie all the loose ends up nicely.

Comment: @ianhanniballake The official docs say : 'A `ListenableWorker` is given a maximum of ten minutes to finish its execution and return a Result.' 
Any suggestions how to execute some work which takes more time maybe hours using a `ListenableWorker`, not able to use Foreground Notification Service directly since my work starts from background and Android 12 has [restrictions on running NotificationService from background](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services#background-start-restrictions).

Answer (score 0):

Well - As the other answers mentioned, if you want to do frequent work (like every 60 sec) you should use foreground service.

Regardless, I'd use coroutines to get out of the main thread. 
Like:

```
        runBlocking(Dispatchers.Default) {
           //If you want to run blocking your code
        }
```

Or using the GlobalScope Launch

```
        GlobalScope.launch {
         //Work in a separated thread (running not blocking)
        }
```

Here is a practical example of getting a location using ListenableWorker and setting up the listeners out of the main thread.

https://github.com/febaisi/ListenableWorkerExample/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/febaisi/listenableworkerexample/data/LocationListenableWorker.kt#L28

Comment: Please nobody use GlobalScope: https://medium.com/@elizarov/the-reason-to-avoid-globalscope-835337445abc