# Equivalent of `await()` in Java for database listeners

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am making an app which downloads byte data from realtime database in firebase. The byte data, which are basically bytes read from a file, is stored as a string. When retrieving the information using a listener, the code just passed the listener without waiting for the information to return. That's to be expected, of course. So as a solution what I did was create an `Interface` like this one:

```
interface DataListener {
    void onSuccess(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot);
    void onStart();
    void onFailure();
}
```

Then I have a method like this one:

```
static void readData(DatabaseReference ref, final DataListener listener) {
    listener.onStart();

    ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            listener.onSuccess(dataSnapshot);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            listener.onFailure();
        }
    });

}
```

So, basically I have a boolean value equal to false, that is turned to true only when the listener is successful. But that does not work with my work-manager. As this method is bypassed too, I'm back at my original problem. I am expecting the work-manager code to stop for the database listener to return something back, write the information gotten to a file and then finally return a result. Here is the work-manager code:

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Result doWork() {

    ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            try {
                String path = getApplicationContext()
                .getExternalFilesDir(null);
                java.io.File directory = new java.io.File(path);

                if (!directory.exists()) directory.mkdirs();
                FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(directory + 
                File.separator + name + "." + extension);

                for (DataSnapshot fileSnap) {
                    output.write(getBytesFromString(fileSnap.child(byteInfo)
                    .getValue(String.class)));
                    Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: output.write() going on");
                }

                output.flush();
                output.close();

                Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: Downloaded the file");

            } catch (Exception ignored) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Failed writing");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
             Log.d(TAG, "Failed");
        }
    });


    Log.d(TAG, "doWork: returned the result");
    return Result.success;
}
```

I am aware of a certain `await()` in TypeScript which I used for my cloud functions. So my question:

> Can I pause the code so the writing process is completed? Because if the code is not paused, the process is done on the main thread and my UI freezes. What's more, is this process needs to be done on the background thread as I am getting a big string and converting it to a byte array, then writing it. So, how can I write that byte data in the background?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `ListenableWorker` seems to be what I want. Can you please add an example code here? The documentation doesn't make much sense to me(I am much frustrated). Thanks!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54083796 for more on `ListenableWorker`. Be careful, in that a `ListenableWorker` `doWork()` method runs on the main application thread -- the expectation is that you will call something that itself does work on a background thread. If Firebase does not give you an option to have the listener be called on a background thread, use chained work with `WorkManager` to have your disk I/O be handled by a separate `Worker` on its background thread.

Comment: Firebase does not support background threading. Just as a second question: I there a background threading class that stops only when you tell it to? I mean I am using a work-manager so the user can exit the app and the file is still downloaded. I would like it to stop on my command. Also, what you mean by `chained work`?

Comment: Sorry, the term that I should have used is ["chained tasks"](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced). "I would like it to stop on my command" -- you can [cancel your work](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/cancel-stop-work).

Comment: Thanks for the elaboration! For the second point, I mean that the background thread keeps running until I stop it. Is there a way to that?

Comment: The output of a task [becomes input of the next task](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced#params).

Comment: Then you are not using `ListenableWorker`. With `ListenableWorker`, you indicate success in your listener itself. `doWork()` returns a `Future`, not a `Result`. In your case, you would update that `Future` in `onDataChange()` and `onCancelled()`. And, in `onDataChange()`, you have your data.