# Co Routines get location from background

Tags: android, location, kotlin-coroutines, android-workmanager

I am sending location data using co routines in workmanager.
I tried just using the workmanager but it does not do async work
I tried ListenableWorkmanager but that was too complicated for me so I am trying to use coroutines.

```
override fun doWork(): Result {

     CoroutineScope(IO).launch  {
        val location = work()
         fusedLocationClient!!.removeLocationUpdates(locationCallback)
          string = logData(location)
     }
        return if(JSONObject(string).get("status") == "1"){
            Result.success()
        }else{
            Result.retry()
        }

    }
```

I am having trouble on how to return the location from the `work` function

```
 private suspend fun work():Location{
...............

 fusedLocationClient!!.lastLocation.addOnSuccessListener { location ->
            if (location != null) {
                mCurrentLocation = location
          // how do I send this location back to the fuction??
            }
        }.addOnFailureListener {
            mLog.i(TAG, it.message)
        }
return mCurrentLocation // if I do this could be a null right?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`Worker`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/Worker) class only supports synchronous work. This means that when you return the result, the code in your worker needs to have completed its execution.

In your case you should use a [`ListenerWorker`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/ListenableWorker) (or a [`CoroutineWorker`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/work/CoroutineWorker) if you prefer to use Kotlin).

Take a look at last year [ADS talk on WorkManager](https://youtu.be/83a4rYXsDs0?t=730), it covers this a bit. You can also view my talk [Embracing WorkManager](https://twitter.com/pfmaggi/status/1148213273000665088?s=20) that covers the difference between the different Worker classes.

Comment: hey I went through your slides and a lot of posts your presentation is good but I am not good with kotlin and  among the posts I found one that is doing what I want.. is this the proper way to do it??
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54083654/how-do-i-run-a-listenableworker-work-on-a-background-thread

Comment: yeah, you can follow that answer.

Comment: Please, don't use coroutines inside a Worker class, use a CoroutineWorker or use a ListenableWorker.

Comment: there are not much examples to go on, I am new and I could not understand much of the code still I will give it a try. Thank u very much for your help.

Comment: I am trying to work with ListenerWorker but the SettableFuture.create is private according to the lint warning and cannot be used. Is that correct or is it a bug as discussed here https://stackoverflow.com/a/52825547/8528047 because I am still getting it on `androidx.work:work-runtime:2.2.0`

Comment: or will this code with a countdown latch will work https://stackoverflow.com/a/50425201/10800406